# Multiple criteria search with IDs

Tags: excel, vba, search, criteria, countif

I don't usually come to Stack Overflow empty handed (without having VBA code) but I honestly don't know how to get the following idea to work.

I'm trying to build a raw data **search engine** which would work by setting 3 criteria in a box/cells on the side of the spreadsheet. The raw data contains sets of IDs in column (A) with various lengths, the search should run once for every set of IDs and look up whether it can match CRITERIA 1 & CRITERIA 2 to column (B) and whether it can match CRITERIA 3 to column (C).

If all three criteria match for one set of IDs then search engine should return "MATCH" in column (D)

[image: see excel example here]

Note note that ultimately the macro should be able to run the search on around 50'000 rows of data and for up to 5 criteria!

How can I start, or what functions should I use?

Comment: Sounds like COUNTIFS should work (though 50000 rows might bog down a bit...)

Comment: When you say "whether it can match CRITERIA 1 & CRITERIA 2 to column (B)" you mean `OR` not `&` right? None of column B has A and B in it...

Comment: How can Criteria 1 & 2 be met for a certain row? And why does row 10 match the criteria? Or row 23?

Comment: @jamheadart I meant CRITERIA 1 and CRITERIA 2 have to *both* match. ID 111 both has both A's & B's same with ID 333

Comment: @M.Schalk As long as ID 111 has CRITERIA 1 *AND* CRITERIA 2 in one of its row the entire ID is flagged as matched

Comment: Ah so it's always referring to the entire ID instead of single rows. Makes it more complex.

Comment: @M.Schalk that's right! :)

Comment: What about defining the datatable as a recordset and using SQL?

Comment: Wondering this **upvote**, SO isn't a free coding service. @Flohabenicht did you at least tried something ? If yes can you please show us your code or the stuff that you tried ? Kindest regards

Comment: Ah ok, makes sense. SO you'd need to identify the row range that `111` covers then search B-rows for existence of Crit1 AND Crit2, then search C for existence of Crit3. Should be doable...but yeah, it'd be an easier job if you got this data into SQL...

Comment: You might be able to use the Advanced Filter, or Power Query. BTW, your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. Having to manually recreate is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful to more people, edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to recreate the same table than you. You can see that I don't need VBA for this. Use directly an IF with a combination of AND/OR, and autofill the column :)

[image]

Comment: Hello Bender, 

Thanks for your response. I actually use to run this "tool" with a combination of COUNTIFS/ORs/ANDs and up to 6 different criteria (incl. criteria or excl. criteria) depending on the constellation you were looking for.  

However, Excel would not support more than 5K lines and I would have to wait around 5 minute before the formula could run in its entirety.

I've now gotten a request to optimize the tool so that the user could run with up to 15 criteria and 50'000 rows of code.